# InAppPurchase implementation

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

How can I test in-app purchase before release?

I have an application which is not in the app store i haven't provide the details for submission of my application in itunesconnect and I want to implement In-app purchase for the same application is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But for that you need to login to your iTunes Connect account and submit details of ur app and then create In-App Purchases from there only. You can test it before uploading it to the app store.
Please do some R&D on your own on google and then come here with the code if u have some problem.